# Memory leak when using AddEmbeddedImage

Tags: php, memory-leaks, phpmailer

Whenever I use `AddEmbeddedImage` in `PHPMailer`, I get this error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\phpmailer\class.smtp.php on line 659

This is **line 659**:

```
$lines = explode("\n", str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r"), "\n", $msg_data));
```

Here is some part of the code:

```
$mail->Body = '
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Sign-Up Verification</title>
        </head>
        <body style="text-align:center;">
            <img src="cid:letterhead">
        </body>
    </html>
';
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('img/letterhead.jpg', 'letterhead', 'letterhead.jpg');
```

The relative path is correct, so I don't think it is the problem. I already tried using absolute path:

```
<img src="C:\xampp\htdocs\project\img\letterhead.jpg"/>
```

Although the error disappeared, no image is being shown in the mail.

Threads about the error says that increasing the memory limit should remove it, but I'm trying to avoid editing `php.ini` just to be safe.  I also looked at threads about using `AddEmbeddedImage()`, but none of the questions say anything about the error, and the syntax is correct.

Should I really increase the memory limit? Or is it a localhost problem?

**UPDATE**

Tried using a smaller image *(1.5mb in size, the original image is 26.7mb)*, the error I'm encountering now is

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\amac2017\phpmailer\class.smtp.php on line 999

**Line 999**:

```
$result = fwrite($this->smtp_conn, $data);
```

Comment: It's not a memory *leak* (that's something different), it just needs quite a lot of memory. Increasing memory allocation or reducing attachment size should fix it, or alternatively, stick it on a web page and send a link to it - it's far more efficient. If you're sending attachments bigger than a couple of megabytes, you should really look at other ways of sending it.

Comment: @synchro Will this problem be solved if I put everything in a web host?

Comment: It's entirely dependent on your memory allocation and how big your attachments are. Where it runs makes no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PHPMailer::AddEmbeddedImage()` is popular to used to add images in the email, so it is unlikely to cause memory leak. It is permissible to adjust the configuration file of PHP as needed. Maybe you can narrow your picture and adjust the php.ini appropriately.

Comment: So the size of the image can also be the culprit?

Comment: And unfortunately, this is not answer but is more of a comment. I'm thankful for the insight but I need to follow SO rules

Comment: Maybe, it might be too big for  your current configuration.

Comment: I see, I'll try to use first a small image

Comment: Good Luck! (Ps: I don`t have 50 reputation, so……)

Comment: If it is really an image size problem, then I'll accept this as the answer